# Collection and view not working in backbone script?

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, pug

Hey guys I am currently following a tutorial and learning backbone, but for some reason I cannot get anything besides the Backbone model to work. Everything underneath it such as the collection or view does not seem to respond when entering things in the console. This is currently my code, I cannot find anything wrong with it and it validates in JSLint. One thing I noticed though is that the video is from before the 1.0 update of backbone. I am using jade for the layout and will include the code below as well.

**UPDATED:** I am working with this now.

```
    (function(){
    //app can be the name of the project/app
    window.App = {
        Models: {},
        Collections: {},
        Views: {},
        Templates: {},
        Routes: {}

    };
    window.template = function (id) {
        return _.template($('#' + id).html());
    };

    //Can get rid of the Collection and views out of the names of each
    //User Model
    App.Models.User = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            firstName: 'J.R.',
            lastName: 'Smith',
            email: 'jsmith@knicks.com',
            phone: '212-424-6234',
            birthday: '03/05/1982',
            city: 'New York'

        },


        location: function(){
            return this.get('firstName') + ' ' + this.get('lastName') + 'is currently in ' + this.get('city') + '.';
        }

    });

    // list of users

    App.Collections.UsersCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: App.Models.User

    });

    //User View
    App.Views.UserView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',

    events: {
        'click .edit':
    },


    template: template('userTemplate'),

    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },

    render: function() {
        var template = this.template(this.model.toJSON());
        this.$el.html(template);
        return this;
        //always return this on render methods
    }

    }); 

    // view for users
    App.Views.UsersView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'ul',

        initialize: function() {

        },

        render: function() {
            this.collection.each(function(user) {
                //user is the model associated to the new created user
                var userView = new App.Views.UserView({model: user});
                this.$el.append(userView.el);
            }, this);
        }
    });

    var userView = new App.Views.UserView({model: User});
    $(document.body).append(userView.render().el);

})();
```

Jade layout page

```
doctype 5
html
    head
        title=title
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/css/style.css', type='text/css')
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/css/bootstrap-responsive.css')
        link(href='/css/bootstrap.css', rel='stylesheet', type='text/css')
        link(href='/css/font-awesome.min.css', rel='stylesheet', type='text/css')
        script(src='/js/jquery.min.js', type='text/javascript')
        script(src='/js/jquery.validate.min.js', type='text/javascript')
        script(src='/js/script.js', type='text/javascript')
        script(src='/js/underscore.min.js', type='text/javascript')
        script(src='/js/backbone.min.js', type='text/javascript')
    body
        div#container
            div#header
            block content 
            include footer
```

Jade index page

```
extends layout

block content
    h1= title
    p Welcome to #{title}
    script(src='/js/main.js', type='text/javascript')
    script(id='userTemplate', type='text/template')
    <%=firstName%>
    button.edit Edit
    <%=lastName%>
    button.edit Edit
    <%=email%>
    button.edit Edit
    <%=phone%>
    button.edit Edit
    <%=birthday%>
    button.edit Edit
    <%=city%>
    button.edit Edit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A view's `render` method simply fills in the view's `el`, someone else has to add that `el` to the page that people will see. You're using `tagName` in your view:

```
tagName: 'li'
```

That just means that Backbone will create an `<li>` as your view's `el`, it doesn't mean that that `<li>` will be added to anything. The usual pattern is for `render` to return `this`:

```
render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
}
```

and then whoever is calling `render` can add the `el` to the page with something like this:

```
var userView = new UserView({model: user});
$(whatever).append(userView.render().el);
```

I do my Backbone work client-side so I'm not sure how that would fit into your set up.

Comment: Ok I edited the code with what I am currently working with, I understand all that but the problem I am having is that isn't something suppose to render on the page. Shouldn't the default show up, or how do I go about doing that? Yes I am using it for client-side and ultimately I will be fetching the data from my db but I just want to get it working without that part at first. Thanks you are awesome btw.

Comment: Does your collection have anything in it when you `this.collection.each(...)`? You should be putting `UserView` instances inside a `UsersView` instance as well, otherwise you'll be trying to add `<li>`s to `<body>` and an [`<li>` can only go inside a `<ul>`, `<ol>`, or `<menu>`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/li.html#li-context).

Comment: Thanks just had a friend come look at it, I didn't realize I was saving the file as a second main.js file so nothing was being changed in the other file. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies here:

```
var userView = new App.Views.UserView({model: User});
$(document.body).append(userView.render().el);
```

Looking at your code I would expect an instance of App.Views.UsersView to be appended, and for it to be populated - in the code above you're pushing in `{ model: User }` to an instance of a UserView instance rather than an instance of UsersCollection to an instance of UsersView.

Firstly your UsersView.render method should `return this;` in order to allow use of the `.render().el` pattern, UsersView handles creating and attaching instances of UserView for each model in the collection so you don't need to worry about this again.

```
render: function() {
    this.collection.each(function(user) {
        //user is the model associated to the new created user
        var userView = new App.Views.UserView({model: user});
        this.$el.append(userView.el);
    }, this);
    return this;
}
```

Then, the following looks right to me:

```
var users_data=[{
    firstName: 'A',
    lastName: 'Person',
    email: 'a@knicks.com',
    phone: '212-424-6234',
    birthday: '03/05/1982',
    city: 'New York'
},
    firstName: 'Another',
    lastName: 'Person',
    email: 'another@knicks.com',
    phone: '212-424-6234',
    birthday: '03/05/1982',
    city: 'New York'
},
    firstName: 'A',
    lastName: 'Person',
    email: 'a@knicks.com',
    phone: '212-424-6234',
    birthday: '03/05/1982',
    city: 'New York'
}];

var users = new App.Collections.UsersCollection( users_data );
var usersView = new App.Views.UsersView( users );

$( document.body ).append( usersView.render().el );
```

Comment: It does not seem to show any of the data when I run the page.

Comment: Thanks just had a friend come look at it, I didn't realize I was saving the file as a second main.js file so nothing was being changed in the other file. Thanks for all your help!